# How do I subtract multiple inputted numbers in a loop?

Tags: c, loops, subtraction

The program should collect inputted numbers from the user through a loop (10 maximum numbers) and breaks if the user enters a negative number. After collecting input, it should calculate the sum, difference, product, and quotient. My problem is that I do not know the right way to find the difference, I know this since the answer from the calculator is different from the program's.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int i;
double number, sum = 0.0, difference = 0, product = 1, quotient = 1;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
  printf("Enter n%d: ", i);
  scanf("%lf", &number);

  // if the user enters a negative number, break the loop
  if (number < 0.0) {
     break;
  }

  sum += number; // sum = sum + number;
  difference = number;
  product *= number;
  quotient = number / quotient;
}

printf("Sum = %.2lf", sum);
printf("\nDifference = %.2lf", difference);
printf("\nProduct = %.2lf", product);
printf("\nQuotient = %.2lf", quotient);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you define the "difference" of 10 numbers? Is the first number added to `0`, and all subsequent numbers are subtracted from the result? Or are all 10 numbers subtracted from the initial number `0`, so that the end result is simply the sum of all numbers multiplied with `-1`?

Answer (score 1):

```
double sum=0, difference=0, product =1 , quotient=1;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
  printf("Enter n%d: ", i);
  scanf("%lf", &number);
  if(number<0){
    break;
  }
  sum += number;
  difference -= number;
  product *= number;
  quotient = number/quotient;
}
```

I am supposing you have no knowledge of array yet.

Comment: yes, it wasn't discussed to us yet and i think we aren't supposed to use it.

Comment: I was just trying to correct the logic. Syntax and indentation was not the motive here. Thanks I have corrected.